# regex hour:minute (hour > 24)

Tags: .net, regex, time, hour

I would like to **validate** and **extract** the **hours and minutes from a string** using Regex in .NET.
Just to recuperate the two numbers, separated(or not) by `:`. Accepted format
`h:m` or `m`. Unaccepted `:m`, `h:`.

EDIT:
*This is to note, that the number of **hours** could overflow the 23 till... **32**.*

The overflow for hours(over 32) and minutes(over 59) I will do after values recuperation(int.Parse)

---

<sub>* *just for fun* maybe there a a relative simple regex that could filter also the >32 for hour and >59 for minute (for *minutes* it could be `[0-5]*[0-9]`, for hours I don't know)?</sub>

Comment: In Java you would just parse the string into a Date object using a non-lenient parser and catch the exception (which denotes a fail). Doesn't exist something in .NET?

Comment: Sorry, but please ask a question. You'll never learn to actually code without that certain trial-and-error attitude. Once you're really stuck, everybody's happy to help you!

Comment: @moritz: this is not code learning. Just a complicate regex IMO.

Comment: I advise you reading more about regular expressions, because it's simple task. Go to http://www.regular-expressions.info/ and when you start feeling a bit comfortable in this subject you can use tools such as http://txt2re.com/. Don't change the order, because otherwise you still won't be able to write any regexps - you must always understand what you are writing.

Comment: @przemoc: thanks for advise and links. I know the first, is interesting the former. However there is a lot of people asking about regex if you send to all of them the expressions.info or the MSDN regex reference I don't know if the answer will satisfy everybody. you can give them also the wikipedia or in general the internet access and tell them: search and learn :) thanks however.

Comment: Brute force! 
(00|01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23):(00|01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|39|40|41|42|43|44|45|46|47|48|49|50|51|52|53|54|55|56|57|58|59)

Comment: @DrJokepu: **:** is not mandatory :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the code for validating (till 32) and also obtaining values is(vb.net version):

```
Dim regexHour As New Regex( _ 
   "((?<hours>([012]?\d)|(3[01]))\:)?(?<minutes>[0-5]?\d)", _
    RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture)
Dim matches As MatchCollection = regexHour.Matches(value)

If matches.Count = 1 Then
  With matches(0)
    ' (!) The first group is always the expression itself. '
    If .Groups.Count = 3 Then ' hours : minutes '
      strHours = .Groups("hours").Value
      If String.IsNullOrEmpty(strHours) Then strHours = "0"
      strMinutes = .Groups("minutes").Value
    Else ' there are 1, 3 or > 3 groups '
      success = False
    End If
  End With
Else
  success = False
End If
```

Thanks everybody contributing to this answer!

Comment: I think you confused the `?` quantifier (zero or one repetition) with the `*` quantifier (zero or more repetitions).

Answer (score 8):

Are you dead set on a regex? Because `DateTime.Parse` would be much simpler and more powerful here.

```
 DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("12:30 AM");
```

Then dt gives you everything you need to know about the time. `DateTime.TryParse()` may be better in case you are less certain it's a time string.

Comment: You could have reason. First of all, I need to exclude any local Culture influence. Secondly, my question was linked more to a Regex exercise.

Comment: Then you should pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.  See my answer.

Comment: I forget one little thing: maxhour = 32 :)

Answer (score 2):

`(?:(\d\d?):)?([0-5][0-9])`

If you want to validate hours:

`(?:([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):)?([0-5][0-9])`

**EDIT**: Tested and corrected.

---

However, the best way to do this is with `DateTime.ParseExact`, like this:  (Tested)

```
TimeSpan time = DateTime.ParseExact(
    input, 
    new string[] { "HH:mm", "H:mm", "mm", "%m" }, //The % is necessary to prevent it from being interpreted as a single-character standard format.
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None
).TimeOfDay;
```

For validation, you can use [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx).

Comment: I tested the regexes and found some mistakes, which I corrected.

Comment: @yeah. as other fixes i could mention `DateTime time` and `new string[]`. However thanks, I appreciate the answer and from regex, and from dateTime perspective.

Comment: `time` is a `TimeSpan`.  (Note the `TimeOfDay` property)  `new [] { }` is C# 3.0 syntax; if you're using C# 2.0, you'll need to write `new string[] { }`.

Comment: Just **"5"** will not parse the **"m"** DateTime...

I used `bool result = DateTime.TryParseExact(
                "5",
                new string [] { "HH:mm", "H:mm", "mm", "m" },
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);`

Comment: You need to use `%m`.  See here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#UsingSingleSpecifiers

Comment: yah             bool result = DateTime.TryParseExact(
                "5",
                new string [] { "%H:%m", "H:%m", "%m"},
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt); worked!

Comment: yah, I have one more cause to use regex instead of DateTime.Parse -  the number of hours in my case will over 24 -- 32.

Comment: ?Regex.IsMatch(**"33:59"**, "(?:([012]?[0-9]|3[01]):)?([0-5][0-9])")
**True** - not good...

Answer (score 1):

Here's the regex string. You can access the named capture groups "hours" and "minutes". Use flags "ExplicitCapture" and "Singleline".

@"^((?<hours>[0-9]{1,2}):)?(?<minutes>[0-9]{1,2})$"

You can test regexes here: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

As mentioned, a DateTime parse call might be better unless you need to validate that only this form is allowed.

Also, negative values aren't permitted, neither are decimals. (But, the regex can be changed to include them if needed).

Comment: hmm... from your tester site: Error: parsing "^((?[0-9]{1,2})\:)?(?[0-9]{1,2})$" - Unrecognized grouping construct.

Comment: Thanks - fixed it. My angle brackets got lost in translation.